# Cannot read property 'xy' of undefined in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My lock command is not working for some reason. It was working before and recently it has been annoying me. A terminal picture is below.

My code was working a month ago and now recently it has been acting up every time I add new code. I have compared my code from a month ago, only new code that I wrote was added.

[image: error message]

```js
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");
const fs =require("fs");

module.exports = {
    name: "Timed Lockdown",
    description: "Start a timed lockdown in a channel.",
    run: async(client, message, args) => {
        const time = args.join(" ");
        if (!time) {
        return message.channel.send("Enter a valid time period in `Seconds`, `Minutes` or `Hours`")
        }
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_SERVER", "MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
            return message.channel.send(`You don't have enough Permisions`)
        }
        message.channel.overwritePermissions([
            {
               id: message.guild.id,
               deny : ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
            },
           ],);
           const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setTitle("Channel Updates")
           .setDescription(`${message.channel} has been locked for **${time}**`)
           .setColor("RANDOM");
           message.channel.send(embed)

           let time1 = (`${time}`)
           setTimeout(function(){
           message.channel.overwritePermissions([
               {
               id: message.guild.id,
               null: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
               },
            ],);
           const embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setTitle("Channel Updates")
           .setDescription(`Locked has been lifted in ${message.channel}`)
           .setColor("RANDOM");
           message.channel.send(embed2);
        }, ms(time1));
        message.delete();
    }
}
```

[image: terminal here]

Comment: please include the error you get when you run the command

Comment: sorry about it. i added it

Comment: Please try not to just include pictures of your code, instead include it in your question as actual text ! This will also improve search results.

Answer (score 2):

You only have a `run` method in the object you're exporting from `lock.js` and you're calling `execute` in `main.js`.

You either need to update the method name in `lock.js` like this (and leave `main.js` as is:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "Timed Lockdown",
    description: "Start a timed lockdown in a channel.",
    execute: async(client, message, args) => {
        const time = args.join(" ");

        // ... rest of code
```

**Or** call the `run` method in `main.js` like this:

```js
if (command === "lock") {
  client.commands.get("lock").run(message, args);
}
```

Comment: it is now saying run is undefined

Comment: You only need to update one file (either `lock.js` or `main.js`). That's why I said **or** in bold ;)